# Http Get request is not working

Tags: scala, httpclient

I am trying to get xml data from apache ranger using it's rest api. Here is my code

```
    val httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient()
    val auth=new AuthScope(host,AuthScope.ANY_PORT)
    val credentials=new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password)
    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider()
          .setCredentials(auth, credentials)
    val httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:6080/service/public/api/repository/1")
    httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml")
    val response = httpclient.execute(httpget)
    val entity = response.getEntity
    if (entity != null) {
      val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()))
      var line = in.readLine()
      var response = new StringBuffer()
      while (line != null) {
        response.append(line)
        line = in.readLine()
      }
      in.close()
      println(response.toString())
    }
```

If i hit this url from browser it shows result fine. But in case of code it returns html.

Any help?

Comment: what does this html say? anything about authentication?

Comment: it say user does not exist

Comment: this works fine using curl command in this format
curl http://my_url.net?param1=12&param2=777 --header "Authorization: Basic XXX" where xxx is encoded username:password

Comment: thanks, it worked with following change
httpget.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
      new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "pswerd"),
      "UTF-8", false))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
val httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient()
    val httpget = new HttpGet("url")
    httpget.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
      new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "pass"),
      "UTF-8", false))
    httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    val response = httpclient.execute(httpget)
    EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())
```

setting authentication in the request.

Thanks